# saving image from URL to server using bluehost - getting an error?

Tags: php, image, bluehost

i'm trying to get an image from a URL and then save it to an images folder on my server. my site is hosted on bluehost and i'm using the following php script...

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png";
$save_name = "logo4w.png";
$save_directory = "/albums/images/art/";

if(is_writable($save_directory)) {
    file_write_contents($save_directory . $save_name, file_get_contents($url));
} else {
     exit("Failed to write to directory ".$save_directory);
}
```

but every time i try this i get the "Failed to write to directory error". I don't really know what i'm doing wrong. i could really use some help.

Comment: You can't write to that directory. Are you sure it's correct? It looks like it should perhaps be a relative directory rather than an absolute one?

Comment: why can't i write to that directory?

Comment: Does that directory exist? Does the user that your PHP code is running as have write permission to that directory?

Comment: yes the directory exists... how do i make sure of the permissions?

Comment: Do you have SSH access? You can see the permissions that way. How did you create the directory originally?

Comment: i just created the empty directory via ftp. yes i have ssh access

Comment: If you created it via FTP, then it will be owned by the FTP user - you'll find that most web hosts have the web user running as a specific user, and you'll need to set that user up as being able to write to that directory. Try SSHing onto the server, changing to that directory, and running `chmod a+w .` to make it writable by any user.

Comment: i'm not familiar with SSHing... could you give me a brief walkthrough? i'd really appreciate it. or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: All you need to do is `ssh <servername>` and log in with your username and password; `cd /albums/images/art/`; and `chmod a+w`.

Comment: i keep getting `no such file or directory`

Comment: Try `cd albums/images/art/` instead. It looks like you've created it from your home directory, instead of the server's root directory.

Comment: alright so i found it. i navigated to the `/art/` folder. i tried `chmod a+w` and got the error `chmod: missing operand after a+w`

Comment: Ah, my mistake - you need a dot at the end: `chmod a+w .` And while you're in that directory, do a `pwd` - that will show you the full path, so you can make sure that it's the same as you've set for `$save_directory`

Comment: ok i think it worked. what exactly did i just do?

Comment: `chmod` changes file permissions. `a+w` means that all users now have write permission; and the dot refers to the current directory. So now your PHP process should be able to write to the directory.

Comment: ok. let me try my script again.

Comment: still failing to write to directory...

Comment: Did you run `pwd` in the directory once you'd used `chmod`? I suspect that you've just got the wrong directory name now.

Comment: i did not. what does `pwd` do? it looks like i'm in the right folder where i want the images to go...

Comment: do i have to do a `chmod a+w` in ever folder in the file structure? all the way back out to home?

Comment: `pwd` just tells you the full path for the current directory

Comment: And you don't need to chmod everything, just the one folder. You should make as few folders as possible writable, as a rule.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30085/discussion-between-patricko-and-andrewsi)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$url = "http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png";
$save_name = "logo4w.png";
$save_directory = $_ENV["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/albums/images/art/"; // This ensures your path is correct
chmod($save_directory,0777); // This will make sure that directory is writeable

if(is_writable($save_directory)) {
    file_write_contents($save_directory . $save_name, file_get_contents($url));
} else {
     exit("Failed to write to directory ".$save_directory);
}
```

Comment: Can you try `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` instead of `$_ENV["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`

Comment: wouldn't the PHP user already need to own the directory for chmod to work programmatically? Otherwise, you could just navigate to any given directory and start writing to it.

Comment: Mmm I'm assuming he is the admin of the account and he should have the access?

Comment: @ISuthanBala - he might have that level of access, but the process running the PHP shouldn't.

Comment: i'm still getting the server error page with `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the actual function is

```
file_put_contents($save_directory . $save_name, file_get_contents($url));
```

and not

```
 file_write_contents($save_directory . $save_name, file_get_contents($url));
```

thanks for your help yall, especially andrewsi